# Print all arraylist items in one row if they are not empty Java

Tags: java

I have an Arraylist (items) and to this arraylist I pass (add) rows that I read from a text file (input = rows from file). The input looks like this "0500123;0501023;050100;
0501023;050100;
etc.
Those lines are added into the arraylist (items) by splitting each line with the actual the delimiter(;).

Lines size (arraylist size) varies from 2 to 6.
What I need is to print all arraylist elements in one row only (meaning all lines from the input still to stay in one row). Looping with for, either returns all elements in a new line or all elements of all arrays (all lines) in a single row.

I created the below code with those "if"s. The code is working, and is printing correctly the results but how can I do it shorter? I tried using a Streams but I couldn't achieve that.

How can I do the following, maybe with a loop?

**Edit:** Thank you are all amazing.

```
ArrayList items= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(";")));
     
if(items.size()==2) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1));
if(items.size()==3) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2));
if(items.size()==4) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3));
if(items.size()==5) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3)+""+items.get(4));
if(items.size()==6) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3)+""+items.get(4)+""+items.get(5));
       }
```

Comment: Use a for loop and print a newline after the loop.

Comment: Take a look at `System.out.print()` instead of `println()`. This prints without the newline character `\n`.

Comment: And put an empty System.out.println() at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a **sublist based on indices** and form the output string.

```
List<String> items = List.of("0500123;0501023;050100".split(";"));
int printFirstN = 2;

String c = String.join(" ", items.subList(0, printFirstN));
System.out.println(c);
```

Output: `0500123 0501023`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```java
if(items.size()==2) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1));
if(items.size()==3) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2));
if(items.size()==4) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3));
if(items.size()==5) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3)+""+items.get(4));
if(items.size()==6) System.out.println(items.get(0)+""+items.get(1)+""+items.get(2)+""+items.get(3)+""+items.get(4)+""+items.get(5));
```

with a loop in the following ways:

```
String output = "";
for (String s : items) output += s;
System.out.println(output);
```

or

```
for (String s : items)
    System.out.print(s);
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
    System.out.print(items.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String extractNumber(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s*;\\s*"))    // \s* - just to exclude spaced
                 .filter(num -> !num.isBlank())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Output:

```
String str = "0500123;0501023;050100;  ; 6666;   ";
System.out.println(extractNumber(str));

050012305010230501006666
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that does what you describe:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input =
                "1;2\n" +
                "1;2;3;4;5\n" +
                "1;2;3\n" +
                "1\n" +
                "1;2;3;4;5;6";
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(input);
        
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scn.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scn.nextLine());
        }
        
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] data = line.split(";");
            for (String s : data) {
                
                // Print each split data and a space with no newlines:
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            
            // Print a line break:
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the program:

```
1 2
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3
1
1 2 3 4 5 6
```